# Change a background color of text by taking text name form url

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change a background colour of text which matches to url value.
I have tried like this

```
<script>
var full_url = document.URL; 
var url_array = full_url.split('=');
var textname = url_array[url_array.length-1]; 


$("a:contains(textname)").css("background-color", "white");
```

But it's not working
can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: change your code like this... **$("a:contains("+textname+")").css("background-color", "white");**

Answer (score 1):

Note that here you aren't using the value of the `textname` variable in your selector, because `"a:contains(textname)"` is a string.

What you probably want to do is:

```
$("a:contains("+textname+")").css("background-color", "white");
```